# Certain Letters cause Index Out of Range CollectionView/TableView UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I have a collectionview inside a tableview and trying to search XML data. My searchcontroller is on my main tableview's view controller and the results are shown on a separate search results view controller. Some letters will search without any problems. I am getting the following index out of range error however, when I search certain letters:

[image: index out of range]

I debugged and found out the filtered data is sometimes different from the returned/showing data:

[image: different array counts]

I tried to add different conditions to handle the different counts, but I either get a crash for the index in cellForItemAt or a crash at didSelectItemAt.

My code:

Main View Controller:

```
var filteredData = [AgeRangeData]()

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredData.removeAll()

    for missingFilteredData in allAgesArray {
        filteredData.append(missingFilteredData)
    }

    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        filteredData = allAgesArray.compactMap {
            var filterObjects = $0
            filterObjects.ageRangeData = $0.ageRangeData.filter {
                $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
            return filterObjects.ageRangeData.isEmpty ? nil : filterObjects
        }

        let searchResultsVC = searchController.searchResultsController as! SearchResultsVC
        searchResultsVC.missingFilteredData = filteredData
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchResultsVC.resultsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty  {
            self.searchBarActive = false
        } else {
            self.searchBarActive = true
            updateSearchResults(for: searchController)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.missingTableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Search Results View Controller:

```
var missingKidData: [AgeRangeData] = []
var missingFilteredData: [AgeRangeData]? = []
var missingKidSearchData: AgeRangeData!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return missingFilteredData?.count ?? 0
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchResultsCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchResultsTableViewCell
        if (missingFilteredData?.count)! > indexPath.row {
            let missingSearchKidData = missingFilteredData![indexPath.row].ageRangeData
            cell.missingKidData = missingSearchKidData[indexPath.row]
            cell.missingResultsImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            cell.missingResultsImage.clipsToBounds = true

            return cell
        } 
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: Where does `missingSearchKidData` come from? How is related to your filtered data?  I note that your filtering code first adds `missingFilteredData` to the `filteredData` and then adds matching data, so you can me up with more elements than in your source data.

Comment: @Paulw11 missingSearchKidData is just a variable that I set in cellForRowAt. AgeRangeData is a array in another array and I use missingSearchKidData to pull out the objects in the AgeRangeData array to present in the tableview. I edited the code with the variable declarations.

Comment: You have a local `miasingSearchKidData` in your `cellForRow`, this is different to the property.

Comment: @Paulw11 I removed missingSearchKidData as a global variable. I am still getting the crash. How is it different to the property if I am setting it equal to it? (let missingSearchKidData = missingFilteredData[indexPath.row.ageRangeData) I understand that missingFilteredData and missingSearchKidData is not equal and that is why it crashes.

Comment: Right, because you have two arrays, one inside the other,  but you are accessing both by `indexPath.row`.  Why should the number of items in the `ageRangeData` array be the same as the number in the outer array?

Comment: It shouldn't. The crash is caused because I am trying to access both the inner and outer array at the same time? or set the inner and outer array equal to each other?

Comment: In your `cellForRowAt` you say `cell.missingKidData = missingSearchKidData[indexPath.row]`.  If `cell.missingKidData` is the data to be shown in a collection view in the cell (and I am guessing here based on your question title, as you haven't shown the cell details) then you probably just want `cell.missingKidData = missingSearchKidData` - i.e. provide the array to the cell, not an element of the array

Comment: It is still crashing. missingSearchKidData is what I assign for the tableview from the filteredData. I have a tableview inside a collectionview, but my search results are shown in a tableview. When I try to assign the label/image values: let searchTitle = missingSearchKidData[indexPath.row].title
let searchImage = missingSearchKidData[indexPath.row].url, it still crashes